# Use react-select@2 with styled-components?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components, react-select

We are using styled-components in the project and we are wondering if there is a way to have a full styling capability of react-select V2. I mean it's certainly possible to use objects to define styling, but it feels rather inconsistent and makes a bit worse DX.

From my understanding, the styled-components work by creating generated `className` and attaching to elements. That would essentially mean I would have to use `components` prop anytime I need to eg. change text color. I cannot use `styles` if I want to avoid object CSS-in-JS. Is that correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply put, if the component you want to style with `styled-components` accepts a `className` property, it can be styled with it using the `styled(Component)` syntax.

I see `react-select` accepts `className` for every component, so it should work fine.

ex:

```
import Select from 'react-select';
import styled from 'styled-components';

styled(Select)`
    background-color: red;
    font-size: 20px;
`;
```

Comment: could you provide an example please, still lost with that